# What to do with a deleted answer?

Tags: support, status-completed

How do I go about dealing with a moderator-deleted answer? In my case, I had posted what was a request for clarification of the question as an answer, since I only had less than 50 rep on the main site, so I couldn't comment. Should I edit the old deleted answer and pray for a mod to show up, or leave the old answer as it is and add a new answer?

Comment: Get 10 more rep and post a comment. Alternatively, if you feel like you can improve your answer so that it should be *undeleted*, edit it and flag it for moderator attention (if that's possible, I'm a bit unsure right now). Alternatively, feel free to ask here on meta to have it looked at. Does that sound alright?

Comment: The original question is here. I fixed my old answer.
http://superuser.com/questions/579545/how-to-tab-completion-when-typing-command-in-tmux

Answer (score 1):

I undeleted your answer. Thanks for bringing this to our attention on meta. I hope to see more posts from you in the future. Have a nice time! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!